# Could this custom WPF TextBox control be replaced with an Attached Property?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, resources, controltemplate, attached-properties

I have a simple control that extends the WPF `TextBox` control. The basic idea is to save space in the UI, by enabling the `TextBox` to display its own label inside it when it is empty.

I have declared one `DependencyProperty` called `Label` in it and have set the `TextBox.Template` property to a `ControlTemplate`. The `ControlTemplate` is the default Windows Aero XAML with the addition of a `TextBlock` placed behind the control that displays the value of the `TextBox.Text` property. Its `Visibility` property is bound with a `Converter` to be visible whenever the `Text` property is empty. (There's a lot and mostly uninteresting, so please excuse the scrollbar).

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="LabelTextBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:Aero="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">
    <Aero:ListBoxChrome Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding UIElement.IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding UIElement.IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label, ElementName=This}" Visibility="{Binding Text, ElementName=This, Converter={StaticResource StringToVisibilityConverter}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="#99000000" Padding="3,0,0,0" />
            <ScrollViewer Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
        </Grid>
    </Aero:ListBoxChrome>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Panel.Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

(The `Name` property of the control is set to `This` for the binding)

So anyway, this all works nicely but I was wondering if I could replace this functionality with an Attached Property. I created an Attached Property called `Label` and added a callback delegate that gets called when the property is set. In this method, I planned to find the `ControlTemplate` from the `Application.Resources` and set the `TextBox.Template` property to it... I couldn't find a way to access the `ControlTemplate` so this is my first question.

How can I access a `ControlTemplate` in the `Application.Resources` in App.xaml from an Attached Property?

The rest of the question is how can I then bind to the Attached Property in the 'ControlTemplate'?

I have tried several things like

```
Text="{Binding Path=(Attached:TextBoxProperties.Label), 
    Source={x:Static Attached:TextBoxProperties}, FallbackValue=''}"
```

but the `TextBoxProperties` class that contains the Attached Property is not static.

UPDATE >>>

Thanks to H.B. I found that I could access the `ControlTemplate` using the following code.

```
ControlTemplate labelControlTemplate = 
    (ControlTemplate)Application.Current.FindResource("LabelTextBoxTemplate");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access the `Application.Resources` from: `Application.Current.Resources`.

The binding should probably be this:

```xml
{Binding (Attached:TextBoxProperties.Label),
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox}}
```

It should not matter if the class containing the property is static, the bindng engine will see whether the property is set on the `TextBox`, it does not care about the declaring class.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks so much. I never cease to be amazed at what you can create in WPF without creating user controls!